# what does taking process to spawn from argv means?

Tags: node.js

The book *"Node.js the right way"* with regards to code example:

```
"use strict";
const
    fs = require('fs'),
    spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    filename = process.argv[2];
if (!filename) {
    throw Error("A file to watch must be specified!");
}
fs.watch(filename, function() {
    let ls = spawn('ls', ['-lh', filename]);
    ls.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
});
console.log("Now watching " + filename + " for changes...");
```

says:

> In an early example of our file-watcher program, we pulled the
>   filename to watch from process.argv. Consider these questions:
>
> - Instead, how would you take the process to spawn from process.argv?

What is the meaning of taking the process to spawn from `process.argv`? All I can take from `process.argv` is plain command line arguments. I cannot take from there a process!

Comment: I dont get what you mean, could you please rephrase the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means taking the arguments describing what process to spawn. Something like:

```
let child = spawn(process.argv[2], process.argv.slice(3));
child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
```